# small problem with .htaccess file?

Tags: php, .htaccess

i have a small .htaccess file which allow me to run 1 html file as php

```
<Files yourpage.html>
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
</Files>
```

i need to edit this script so it run all .html and .htm files as .php
and i need this to apply for the files not only yourpage.html
i tried to do it like that

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .php .html
```

but it doesn't make any sense 
i though to remove yourpage.html and put *.html but i don't if its the right way or not

Comment: This seems to be already answered here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687208/using-htaccess-to-make-all-html-pages-to-run-as-php-files

Comment: Possible duplicate of [problem with htaccess file and handlers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7127156/problem-with-htaccess-file-and-handlers)

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
```