# problem with htaccess file and handlers?

Tags: php, .htaccess

i asked a question if i can execute html files as php files and i got those answers

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .php .html
```

and another answer

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

and here is another one

```
RemoveHandler .html .htm
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .htm .html
```

and i got 1 problem
when i used to write any condition to add type it send me to download the page instead of run it
for example if i have a file index.html which have php code
after i create the .htaccess and write

```
RemoveHandler .html .htm
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .htm .html
```

then try to navigate the link it send me to download index.html instead of run it

Comment: Original question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7123560/small-problem-with-htaccess-file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using .htaccess to make all .html pages to run as .php files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687208/using-htaccess-to-make-all-html-pages-to-run-as-php-files)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AddType is used to assign a MIME type to a file suffix.

F.e. to override the MIME type of an PDF *sic

```
AddType text/plain .pdf
```

This will force the browser to load and show a PDF as plain text, because server is sending the text/plain MIMe type. But many applications handle files by content and not by suffix.

```
RemoveHandler
```

This is unnecessary, you don't want to remove anything from the standard configuration.

```
AddHandler handler-name .htm
```

This should do it, but it depends on your server configuration. You need the right "handler-name".

Standard handler-name for most Apache servers with PHP installed is

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .htm
```

but it could differ and it depends on your configuration. If you are using a shared or managed hosting without access to the Apache configuration file, you should ask your hoster.

I was using shared hosting with handler-names like

```
AddHandler php4-cgi .php .html

or

AddHandler php52-cgi .php .html

and another was using totally different way like

AddType x-mapp-php5 .php .php5 .htm .html
```

Otherwise have a look on your Apache configuration file. This [page](http://www.devside.net/articles/php) may be helpful to find the right section and to adapt.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .htm .html
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Exactly the same problem, the basic code forces page download, but this:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .php .htm .html
```

...rectified the issue & worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using fcgi none of the above will work ;
you need

```
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
<Files ~ (\.html)>
    SetHandler fcgid-script
    FCGIWrapper /var/www/cgi-bin/cgi_wrapper/cgi_wrapper .html
    Options +ExecCGI
    allow from all
</Files>
```