# Select the last active li class in a CSS nav menu

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I need to color ONLY the last li with the class default using only CSS.  Editing the HTML is not an option.  IE9+ is fine. How do I color only the last link?  This is just an example and the menu is dynamic so using last child or specifying the exact last link is not an option.  I have a nav menu like this:

```
<ul>
    <li class="default">
        <a href="#">About Us</a>
        <ul>
            <li class="default">
                <a href="#">Where we live</a>
                <ul>
                    <li class="default">
                        <a href="#">Make this link red only</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Directions</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
     </li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: I would prefer not to but I am getting the feeling that I might have to :(  It would still be easier for me to add jquery than to change the html sadly.

Comment: The jquery solution would be: $("li.default:last a").css("color", "red");

Comment: I don't mean to question your setup, but why can't you change the HTML?

Comment: I can't change the HTML because it is being auto generated by a CMS that unfortunately I cannot change at this time.  Believe me, I would like to!

Comment: Not to sound like a broken record, but does your CMS run on PHP by any chance? :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As for a pure CSS approach, IE9 supports these pseudo selectors. This could also work in something like jquery as well. However, the problem with this code is if you have more than one default, then it would colour those.

```
li.default > a:only-child {
  color:red;            
}​
```

Comment: I have been working with this and got `li.default>a:only-child { color:red; }`  which works when the active element is on the last level but on the second and first levels this does not work

Comment: @faithfulprogrammer then maybe `li.default > a { color:red; }` in addition to the above selector?

Comment: Works if there is definitely only one default on the last level.

Comment: +1 for getting the closest using pure CSS.  I will mark this as the accepted answer because I am gathering that what I truly am looking for cannot be acheived with just CSS.  I will be using apathetic's jquery to solve this problem.  Thanks for your help guys!

Comment: I would normally say go for the CSS if it works, but when it comes to using jQuery for simple highlighting like this, I'd recommend a server side (e.g. PHP) solution instead as it's much lighter and won't slow anything down (most webhosts support PHP nowadays)

Answer (score -1):

I think that [this PHP solution](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/keepingcurrent/) would be best in your case ([here's a PHPfiddle demo](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/fxb-ukv) I made: hit 'Run' and wait a few seconds).

To implement this, add this to the top of your HTML file:

```
<?php $thisPage='Make this link red only'; ?>
<html><head>
```

And then add in this PHP (inside the `<?php` and `?>` tags) to all of your navigation items:

```
     <ul>
        <li <?php if ($thisPage=='About Us') echo ' id="currentpage"'; ?>>
            <a href="#">About Us</a>
            <ul>
                <li<?php if ($thisPage=='Where we live') 
          echo ' id="currentpage"'; ?>>
                    <a href="#">Where we live</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li<?php if ($thisPage=='Make this link red only') 
          echo ' id="currentpage"'; ?>>
                            <a href="#">Make this link red only</a>
                        </li>
                        <li <?php if ($thisPage=='Directions') 
          echo ' id="currentpage"'; ?>>
                            <a href="#">Directions</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
         </li>
     </ul>
```

And then set your CSS to:

```
#currentpage a { color: red; }
```

You'll also have to rename your `index.html` as `index.php`, or the better solution would be to use .htaccess (assuming you're running an Apache server) to [parse PHP inside HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687208/using-htaccess-to-make-all-html-pages-to-run-as-php-files) files.

Comment: Currently my setup does not use PHP at all, so I cannot use this solution

Comment: Ah, sorry to hear — but hopefully someone else might :)