# is $_SESSION variable is available only to php file and not to html files?

Tags: php, html, session-variables

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>

    </title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        if($_SESSION['status']=='loggedin'){
            echo $_SESSION['name'];
        }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

I started a session for keeping track of logged in users. The same code I put into a profile.html file and tried to redirect to this page if a log in attempt is successful, but I couldn't fetch any information from `$_SESSION` variables into that file, but when I changed the file extension to profile.php it worked nicely.

Comment: While what `Marcel Korpel` stated below is true, you can run `.html` files as `php`, simply by adding this to your `.htaccess` file `AddType application/x-httpd-php .html`

Comment: @Fred But then *all* html files will be treated as PHP scripts, with a minor drawback on performance.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel Yes that's true. But if the OP really wants to run scripts under the `.html` file convention, then he/she will have to make that choice. It's a last resort which personally, one that I don't use.

Comment: @Fred          will u please explain it more generally or provide me a link where i can understand this thoroughly. i mean i am not understanding where is this .htaccess file or i have to create it and where to put "AddType application/x-httpd-php .html" this line?

Comment: @buet_baba You can Google it with the following link that will show you many pages for you to read up on. https://www.google.com/search?q=run%20html%20as%20php&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using .htaccess to make all .html pages to run as .php files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687208/using-htaccess-to-make-all-html-pages-to-run-as-php-files)

Comment: @buet_baba In short, you would be telling the server to `add a condition` to any (all) .html files to run as if they were .php script files.

Comment: Read up on what PHP is at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP - http://php.net/manual/en/intro-whatis.php

Comment: @buet_baba You're welcome. Enjoy the adventure and happy coding! Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP scripts are by default only interpreted in .php files (unless you tell the PHP interpreter to do otherwise, e.g., using an .htaccess file). So, you can't use `$_SESSION` variables in an .html file.

Answer (score 0):

You can write **php code only in php file** and **html in html file or php file**.