# Why my PHP get changed to a comment?

Tags: php, comments

on a webpage `view-source:http://cordbloodcenter.com/en/Corporate/Cord-blood.alej.html`  I just wrote a short PHP code but when I check source code, the PHP code font is green -> it change to a comment.

the PHP code is:

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("units.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
echo fread($myfile,filesize("units.txt"));
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

Why my PHP get changed to a comment?
Thanks for help,
-Luxqs

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: it's unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Sorry, question is in headline: Why my PHP get changed to a comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the file extension `.html` is not parsed by the PHP interpreter. You can do the simple thing, and change the file extension to `.php` or make PHP parse `.html` files.

Go to the PHP ini file. At the end you will find this:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

change it to:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html .htm
```

and a restart will activate it. If you use Apache it would be this command:

```
httpd -k restart
```

This is quite straightforward. Personally I prefer to keep the `.html` and `.htm` extension and hide the fact that I am using PHP. Why give away more information than needed? (not that obfuscation is a good way to implement security, but it cannot hurt). I also don't need to make an artificial distinction between pure html files and php file.

The downside is that all html files will go through the PHP parser, and this will be a tiny extra load on your server.

Comment: Thanks, I dont have access, is there any other way?

Comment: There are a lot of answers on StackOverflow. For instance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687208/using-htaccess-to-make-all-html-pages-to-run-as-php-files You should be able to use a `.htaccess` file, simply upload it with FTP as any other file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to rename the file to file with `.php` extention! and then make sure you are opening it via a web server so that the php code gets compiled!

Comment: Thanks, I dont have to rename all .html files to .php. Is there other way? Thanks