# PHP 5.4 - My file includes being commented out after upgrade

Tags: php, html, css

I'm updating the site from PHP 5.3 to 5.4 and in the process the code breaks.  What might cause this?

When I use chrome developer tools it shows the header.html being commented out as well as my other "includes" that I use throughout the page including the footer as well.  The CSS is still good as it is a link in the header, but it can't apply it to anything as it has no content tags to apply classes or ID's css to.

[image: Commenting out code]

In 5.3 it did not comment this out as it does in 5.4
Filename does end in .htm and has the php include in it, however why would it work in 5.3 and not in 5.4 if that is the problem?
Here is the code of the page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<title>Barbourville Kentucky Ky City Guide : Auto Sales</title>

<meta name="Author" content="On-line Advertising London, KY Kentucky">
<META NAME="revisit-after" CONTENT="10 days">
<meta name="KeyWords" CONTENT="barbourville ky, barbourville kentucky, barbourville, ky, kentucky, auto, sales, used, new, Barbourville, ky, kentucky, auto, sales, used, new, Barbourville, ky, kentucky, auto, sales, used, new">
<meta name="Description" CONTENT="Auto Sales in and around Barbourville, Ky. New, used, auto, sales in and Barbourville, Kentucky. Kentucky">

<link href="../../ola.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>
<body>


<?php include("../../header.html"); ?>
<div class="indexadarea">

<br>

<p class="categorypageheaders">Auto Sales</p>



<a class="link5" href="http://www.kbb.com/"   >Click here for Kelly Blue Book Trade-in Report</a><br><br />

<a class="link5" href="http://www.edmunds.com/"   >Click here for Edmund&#39;s Consumer Information Experts</a><br><br />

<a class="link5" href="../financial/creditreports.htm">Credit Reports</a>


        <hr>
        <br>
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" width="637" height="250" cellspacing="0" bordercolor="#000000">
          <tr>
            <td><?php include("http://www.londonky.com/client_indexes/pickardchrysler/"); ?></td>
          </tr>
        </table>

        <br>
        <hr>


        <br>
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" width="637" height="250" cellspacing="0" bordercolor="#000000">
          <tr>
            <td><?php include("http://www.londonky.com/client_indexes/cornettchevrolet/"); ?></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <br>
        <hr>
        <br>
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" width="637" height="250" cellspacing="0" bordercolor="#000000">
          <tr>
            <td><?php include("http://www.londonky.com/client_indexes/hermansclassics/"); ?></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <br>
        <hr>
        <br>
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" width="637" height="250" cellspacing="0" bordercolor="#000000">
          <tr>
            <td><?php include("http://www.londonky.com/client_indexes/kyautoexchange/"); ?></td>
          </tr>
        </table>

        <br>
        <hr>
        <br>

                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" width="637" height="250" cellspacing="0" bordercolor="#000000"><tr><td>
<?php include("http://www.londonky.com/client_indexes/visoneautomart/"); ?></td></tr></table>





        <br>
        <hr>
        <br>
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" width="637" height="250" cellspacing="0" bordercolor="#000000">
          <tr>
            <td><?php include("http://www.londonky.com/client_indexes/jamessmith/"); ?></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <br>



        <div class="singlelinespacer" style="clear:both"></div>


          <p class="singlelinetitle">B  &amp; B Auto Sales</p>
          <p class="singlelineaddress">Barbourville Rd., Gray, KY</p>
          <p class="singlelinephone">(606) 528-9515</p>

    <div class="singlelinespacer" style="clear:both"></div>

        <p class="singlelinetitle">Bargo Motor Co</p>
          <p class="singlelineaddress">1714 Ky 3439</p>
          <p class="singlelinephone">(606) 546-2022</p>

    <div class="singlelinespacer" style="clear:both"></div>

       <p class="singlelinetitle">Bimble Auto Sales</p>
          <p class="singlelineaddress">US Highway 25</p>
          <p class="singlelinephone">(606) 546-2132</p>

    <div class="singlelinespacer" style="clear:both"></div>

       <p class="singlelinetitle">Clark  Self Storage &amp; Motor Sls.</p>
          <p class="singlelineaddress">323 Cumberland Ave</p>
          <p class="singlelinephone">(606) 546-4125</p>

    <div class="singlelinespacer" style="clear:both"></div>

      <p class="singlelinetitle">E Z Auto Sales</p>
          <p class="singlelineaddress">Highway  1304</p>
          <p class="singlelinephone">(606) 546-6437</p>

    <div class="singlelinespacer" style="clear:both"></div>

      <p class="singlelinetitle">Gray&#39;s Motor Sales</p>
          <p class="singlelineaddress">1158 S US  Highway 25E</p>
          <p class="singlelinephone">(606) 546-8119</p>

    <div class="singlelinespacer" style="clear:both"></div>

     <p class="singlelinetitle">Hillbilly  Auto Sales</p>
          <p class="singlelineaddress">HC 84</p>
          <p class="singlelinephone">(606) 546-6329</p>

    <div class="singlelinespacer" style="clear:both"></div>

      <p class="singlelinetitle">Jones Motor Sales</p>
          <p class="singlelineaddress">Highway 25 E</p>
          <p class="singlelinephone">(606) 546-6537</p>

    <div class="singlelinespacer" style="clear:both"></div>

       <p class="singlelinetitle">Mills Used Cars</p>
          <p class="singlelineaddress">HC 81</p>
          <p class="singlelinephone">(606) 545-9672</p>

    <div class="singlelinespacer" style="clear:both"></div>

      <p class="singlelinetitle">Premier Auto Sales</p>
          <p class="singlelineaddress">53 Knox Plz</p>
          <p class="singlelinephone">(606) 545-0256</p>

    <div class="singlelinespacer" style="clear:both"></div>






<br>

</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>

<?php include("../../footer.html"); ?>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sounds like a server config problem. I'd try renaming the file to `.php`

Comment: its related to IDE, it seems. File has been modified by the IDE. Always version control(git, svn) your code to find out the diff between files.

Comment: Your HTML files need to run as PHP: [one possible solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687208/using-htaccess-to-make-all-html-pages-to-run-as-php-files).

Comment: Yeah, that what I thought too, but it doesn't make sense to work in 5.3.  Anyway, some sort of config problem and renaming to .php works.

Comment: @camdixon in that case, your previous config was set to parse `.html` files as PHP. Your current config is not

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs over at http://serverfault.com/