# what code do i put in .htacess to use php?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

Just wanted to know what code I have to put in my .htaccess file so my html pages read php that im going to put in there, (just a contact form), I did find it once but can't remember, sorry and thanks.

Comment: PHP is a server side language. So you need to install a server and then run php file on that.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, do you mean rewriting URLs in such a way that for example `contact.php` is rewritten to `contact.html`?

Comment: Thank you for the information guys. php is something new to me at the moment, i'm first year web designer learning html5 and css3, php is something I'm looking into at the moment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using .htaccess to make all .html pages to run as .php files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687208/using-htaccess-to-make-all-html-pages-to-run-as-php-files)

Answer (score 2):

You have to convert your html files to php

put this line in your .htaccess if you're using apache2

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

but make sure that your .htaccess file is in the root directory of the website

Comment: *Convert your html files to php*? No conversion takes place.

Answer (score 1):

If you want PHP in HTML files to be interpreted just add this line to your .htaccess file:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML Pages don't read your PHP. Instead Apache is reading your file and executes it with a PHP interpreter if some PHP is in there.
Just in case you have a debian server with apache2 you can `apt-get install php5`. But there is a lot more work to do, for example FCGI and so on.