# PHP in HTML Form Action Tag

Tags: php, html

First PHP page, so this is likely a problem surfacing out of something stupid I'm missing, but I'm not sure what. I'm following the tutorial on [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_form_validation_complete) to create a form with protection from XSS, but when I use the code`<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'); ?>">`, it is parsed such that the first `>` is associated with the `form` tag, so the quotes are mismatched, and the action doesn't complete correctly.

This is what the page looks like:

[image: Screenshot]

EDIT:
Full Code Below

```
<body>
<?php
    $fname = $lname = $email = $student = "";
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
    {
        $fname = $_POST["fname"];
        $lname = $_POST["lname"];
        $email = $_POST["email"];
        switch($_POST["student"])
        {
            case "u":
                $student = "Undergraduate";
                break;
            case "g":
                $student = "Graduate";
                break;
            default:
                $student = "Non-Student";
        }   
    }
?>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'); ?>">
    <p>First Name: <input type="text" name="fname"> </p>
    <p>Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname"> </p>
    <p>Email: <input type="email" name="email"> </p>
    <p>Student Status: <select name="student">
                        <option value="u">Undergraduate</option>
                        <option value="g">Graduate</option>
                        <option value="x">Non-Student</option>
                    </select> </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php
    echo "<h3>Input:</h3>"
    echo "Name: " . $fname . " " . $lname . "<br>";
    echo "Email: <a href=mailto:" . $email . ">" . $email . "</a><br>";
    echo "Student: " . $student;
?>
</body>
```

Comment: is `<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'); ?>">` inside a file with `.php` extension ?

Comment: is your file a `.php` extension? doesn't look like it. Or it's not being parsed because you don't have a web server setup (properly). and/or you're passing this through a web browser using `file:///file.php` rather than `http://localhost/file.php`

Comment: (1) is your file `.php`, (2) are you accessing it on a live server - `http`/`localhost` - or as a direct file - `C://`?

Comment: It is a `.php` file. @Fred-ii- I'm not sure what you mean by not having a web server set up. Perhaps I used the wrong word with 'parsed'. All I meant is that the "> at the start of the page should actually be the closing quote and caret for the `form` tag.

Comment: reload all comments. some were edited (including mine) in order to add more information as to the probably cause.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-i-can-see-it-on-source-code-of-page

Comment: plus, you'll need to post your code. An "image of", isn't enough. A web server is required to run PHP files. They do not run like regular `.html` files.

Comment: @Fred-ii- So it sounds like the question I should be asking is how do I set up a local web server so I can test the PHP files?

Comment: missing semi-colon in `echo "<h3>Input:</h3>"` error reporting would catch that as a parse error.

Comment: depends what platform you're using. Mamp runs off a Mac, Wamp off of Windows, and Xampp runs off of Windows, Mac and Linux. You'll need to Google "how to setup a web server PHP".

Comment: https://www.apachefriends.org/ is where you find XAMPP.  It's very easy to install and get working.

Comment: @Fred-ii- That was the issue. If you want to add your comment as an answer, I'll mark it.

Comment: @Aliden I have posted my answer below, *cheers*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.html` files do not get parsed like `.php` files do, therefore you will need to install a Webserver on your system.

Sidenote: You can instruct Apache to treat `.html` files as PHP, if and when the time comes that you want to do this, it is possible.

- Here is an article on Stack: [Using .htaccess to make all .html pages to run as .php files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4687208/)

`.php` files cannot be run directly from a web browser, unless they are parsed and running off a server or a hosted site.

They require to be accessed as `http://localhost/file.php` from a local machine.

Depending on your platform, you can use Xampp which runs on Windows, Mac and Linux.

- https://www.apachefriends.org/

Wamp:

- http://www.wampserver.com/en/
- http://www.easyphp.org/

Mamp (Mac):

- https://www.mamp.info/

---

Plus, you have a few syntax errors.

```
action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'); ?>">
                                      ^
```

that should be a square bracket, rather than a parentheses.

```
action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
```

and `echo "<h3>Input:</h3>"` is missing a closing semi-colon.

Those would throw/cause a parse error.

Answer (score 1):

The solution may be apparent, the closing bracket is mismatched.

Change:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'); ?>">
```

To:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
```

Notice `['PHP_SELF')` and `['PHP_SELF']`.