# Including PHP with HTML not interacting correctly

Tags: php, html, include

I'm trying to include some PHP script in with a HTML file, while I have found the command that achieves this, there seems to be an error in the way that I've layed out my code. I feel like I've missed a parentheses or something.

Here is a section of my HTML:

```
<title>Web Workers :: Home</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
echo "<h1>Test</h1>";
include_once("htmlstatic.php");
?>

<nav id="navlist">
<ul>
<li class="links"> <a href="index.html">Home</a>                </li>
<li class="links"> <a href="topic1.html">Web Workers</a>        </li>
<li class="links"> <a href="register.html">Register</a>         </li>
<li class="links"> <a href="quiz.html">Quiz</a>                 </li>
<li class="links"> <a href="results.html">Results</a>           </li>
<li class="links"> <a href="about.html">About</a>               </li>
<li class="links"> <a href="enhancements.html">Enhancements</a> </li>
</ul>   
</nav>
<hr class="whitehr"/>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my PHP:

```
<?php
echo "<h1>Web Workers</h1>";
echo "<hr class='whitehr'/>";
echo "<p>test</p>";
?>
```

Here is the output
[image: Output]

Comment: *"Here is a section of my HTML:"* - Give that file a `.php` extension.

Comment: As @Fred-ii- says, the problem is that your server is parsing the file not as PHP, but as simple HTML. You need to give it a .php extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your file has `.html` extension that's why server cannot interpret the code starts with `<?php`

either tell server to interpret `.html` as `.php` or use `.php` file extension

for method first try below in `.htaccess` file

```
RemoveHandler .html .htm
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .htm .html
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot include a `.php` file in `.html` file, nor can you execute a `php` code in a `.html` file, rename your `.html` to `.php` to execute the `php` code. For your php code to be interpreted your files must have .php extension.

**Edited:** 
As you did not mention in the question i am assuming that you are using the default php installation, with no setting to include PHP files in an HTML file.

Comment: ahem, not entirely true

Comment: like... Google Apache html as PHP

Comment: btw, that's not my downvote

Comment: @Fred-ii- though its true but its kind of mistake user is making (imo OP have no idea about it )

Comment: @Fred-ii-, yes that is correct but i am talking as per the OP requirements.

Comment: and I'm talking about your answer. You can run `.html` as PHP and you can include PHP into HTML and vice-versa. I've been doing it for years

Comment: @Sourabh even you can do it in htaccess like you can remove .php extension you can also rename .html it to .php

Comment: Upvoted to counteract downvote. What he is saying is true. The user never dictated what version they were using of Apache and PHP so I'm assuming it's default installation. If you try to run php in an html file then it won't execute.

Comment: I never said the answer was completely wrong @MorganGreen I said it's not entirely true. Plus, that wasn't my downvote, as I stated earlier. I've been dealing with using `.html` as PHP for years; I think I know what I'm talking about here.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I never said you didn't, but if the OP hadn't specified that they had modified anything to enable php in html, then I'm simply stating that it's extremely doubtful that they had or else you would think that they would have stated it. I also never said you were the cause of the downvote I just think the downvote was unmerited.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687208/using-htaccess-to-make-all-html-pages-to-run-as-php-files http://php.about.com/od/advancedphp/p/html_php.htm to name a few @Sourabh

Comment: @MorganGreen I always like giving a "not so entirely true" answer, the benefit of the doubt. ;-)

Comment: come on let it go ... @Fred-ii- i know you are telling right but most of newcomers have no idea about it, though its good to include relevant information ;)

Comment: @Fred-ii-, you are right i am happy that you pointed out the additional thing , you spent your time for me thanks.

Comment: @NullPoiиteя yeah, I learned that lesson *real hard* myself years ago. Always nice to *share the wealth* ;-)