# How to access a css file and its styles from another php file?

Tags: php, html, css

I am looking to include or gain access of a css file using another php. I know it's possible but I don't exactly know how to do it, the following is my css file:

```
 <style type="text/css">
        .titleStyle
        {
            color:black;
            text-align: center;
            font-family: Stencil Std; 
        }
</style>
```

I am planning to use this file and the style within it in another php or html script. I heard the word include or require might be needed, could someone please help me with this situation? thanks!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Answer (score 1):

### It's simple:

```
<?php
  include "css/style.css"; // include the 'style.css' file in a directory
?>
```

### More detail: read-on

#### Using `include`:

```
<?php
  include "css/style.css"; // include the 'style.css' file in a directory named 'css'
  include "style.css"; // include the 'style.css' file in current directory
  include "../style.css"; // include the 'style.css' file in parent directory
?>
```

#### Using `require`:

```
<?php
  require "css/style.css"; // include and require the 'style.css' file in a directory named 'css'
  require "style.css"; // include and require the 'style.css' file in current directory
  require "../style.css"; // include and require the 'style.css' file in parent directory
?>
```

**Note 1: What's the *difference* between** `include` **and** `require` **?**

`include` ***includes*** the file, and it throws an error when the file is not found.
`require` includes and ***require*** the file, and it exit (stop reading) the file when the file is not found.

**Note 2: How to use this script in *HTML*?**

It would not be easy to use this script in an `.html` file. But this does not means it's impossible. The simplest way to do this is to use `.htaccess` file. You can create a file named `.htaccess` and put the following content in there:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

Note that this might not always work when your/your-hosting-company's computer or server does not support htaccess. And in my opinion, this is not a smart thing to do.

More Info:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php
[Using .htaccess to make all .html pages to run as .php files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687208/using-htaccess-to-make-all-html-pages-to-run-as-php-files)

Comment: you are trying too hard for acceptance

Answer (score 1):

Consider having a separate header file like a Header.php.

HEADER.PHP

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>TITLE</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="layout.css"/>
</head>
```

and then include it into the file you wish to

```
<?php include 'header.php'; ?>
```

Comment: I don't think it's a very idea because it would be slower to load the page.

Comment: Also, this does not work, because the css file contain the `<style>` tag.

Comment: @CaiHaoyang, including a header (which calls a simple css style sheet) in a file isn't a good idea and won't work?.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
include ('css/style.css');
```