# How to add php script in Szimek/Signature_Pad (index.html)?

Tags: javascript, php

PHP tag is not working in my `index.html file`

But if I change `index.html` to `index.php` then it prints the `app.js` code on index file.

Answer (score 1):

What web server are you using?  Your web server is probably not configured to run PHP files with an `html` extension.

According to [the answer from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687208/using-htaccess-to-make-all-html-pages-to-run-as-php-files), you can configure Apache to run files with an `html` extension as PHP using a `.htaccess` file.

> Create a .htaccess file at the root of your website and add this line:
>
> [Apache2 @ Ubuntu/Debian: use this directive]
>
> ```
> AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
> ```

Comment: You need to configure your Apache to run files with `html` extension as PHP files. See my updated answer.