# Allowing *.html pages to execute PHP script

Tags: php, html, iis, ssi

I understand that there are a lot of seemingly the same questions over here. I have tried all the given solutions in the answers I could find but still no succes.

I have a Microsoft 2012 R2 Server running IIS 8.5. Because my old website was using .htaccess I installed Helicon Ape so I could still make use of .htaccess.
This seems to run good. I tested it by adding this to the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^test\.html http://www.google.com/? [R=301,L]
```

Whenever I open the test.html file it will redirect me to Google so I guess this is working fine.

Now I tried to add the following line to the .htaccess:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

And after this failed I tried the following line:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .html .htm
```

Still no succes. After this I tried to let the FastCGI Handler process all html files. Nothing changed.
Last but not least I have tried to use the Server Side Includes from this video:
[YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=foLClXY3wTE)

Still it didn't work. I have my .htaccess file in my root folder. Are there any other options I could try?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using .htaccess to make all .html pages to run as .php files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687208/using-htaccess-to-make-all-html-pages-to-run-as-php-files)