# PHP being commented out when uploaded to server (Ipage)

Tags: php, server, web-hosting

I am new to PHP and am trying to run my first script. I read that to to run php on your pc, you have run a server on it which I didn't feel like doing.

So instead I am trying to run it on a server hosted by Ipage.com

The program is just a basic html file with a set of full  tags

I have tried linking windows explorer using ftp, using the "upload" button on the website and directly editing the file using the editer on the site. When ever I add the php tags and save or upload the file, when I go to view it on the ipage file manager, they are commented out

This is what happens to the file when I upload it

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Striations</title>
  <head> 

    <link href="css/LandingPageStyle.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

<body>
    <!--?php echo "HELLO"; ?--> //originally <?php echo "HELLO"; ?>
    <h2>Our site is currently under construction, please check back later!</h2>
    <img src="media/construction man.png"></img>
</body>

</html>
```

I'm totally new to php and hosting and stuff and I could be missing some important step regarding how to run php

I'd appreciate and explanation of how php is transferred into html before being sent to the browser

EDIT:: I know as a fact that ipage supports php, they had mentioned something about changing my root file directory, but even when I moved my files to where they said, it did the same thing

Is there something else I should be doing to enable php?

Comment: Bad hosting provider.

Comment: Does your webspace on Ipage.com support `PHP`?

Comment: Have you enabled PHP? http://www.mywebsitetraining.com/details/ipage-php-info-configurationsettingsversion/

Comment: I have iPage and have never had this happen...

Comment: @mario.klump ipage supports php. Is there something I have to do to make _my site_ recognize and run the script

Comment: Does the name of your file end with .php?

Comment: @Tim did you do anything else besides just upload the file (i.e. save your files in the /home/users/web... directory like they said)

Comment: It is an html file with php tags... I'm supposed to save it as .html, right?

Comment: it was the file type, thanks @Tim

Comment: I strongly recommend installing a small development server on your computer.  It's surprisingly easy.  Try XAMPP;  it will work on any operating system, and it's pretty self-explanatory, and you don't need to worry about the quirks of various remote servers.  It even has a few test scripts.   You can get a full script running before you upload it.  https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html

Comment: @nomistic I had never heard of that before, I check it out. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is an html file with php tags... I'm supposed to save it as .html, right?

If you saved this as `index.html` then the PHP parser won't run it by default. Either name it `index.php` or (if you can) [use htaccess to parse HTML files as PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687208/using-htaccess-to-make-all-html-pages-to-run-as-php-files)