# How to convert .html to .php with singleshot?

Tags: php, html

I have hundreds of pages .html in my local folder and I want to convert them to .php.

Is there any way to do this in a single shot instead of going to replace every ".html" with ".php"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Windows you can start a command prompt (cmd), `cd` to the right directory, and use this command:

```
ren *.html *.php
```

Or, without using `cd`, use this command:

```
ren C:\Path\To\Your\Files\*.html *.php
```

`*` is a [wildcard](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490639.aspx) which you can use to refer to all files. Windows supports using these wildcards too when renaming files in bulk.

Note: Make a copy first or make sure everything is committed in your version control. If things go wrong you would want to be able to restore the situation when you do a bulk action like this.

Comment: what is this supposed to do, `*` is for the file name??

Comment: `*` is all file names. [It's a wildcard](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490639.aspx).

Comment: will it change all html in other folders? i only need single folder .

Comment: No, this is just in the current folder in the command prompt. Start `cmd`, and inside the command prompt, make sure you use the `cd` command first, to go to the right directory.

Comment: yeah..on that way..i will check

Answer (score 3):

if you have access to `.htaccess` and don't want to change the `.html` to `.php` manually.  add this to your `.htaccess`

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

this will treat your `.html` files as `.php`

Comment: this is nice idea, i was looking for it

Comment: You can check this answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4687217/5052778