# Cannot include PHP file to my HTML

Tags: php, html, xampp

I'm trying to access my function.php file so I'll be able to use the functions inside it. But I can't connect it. I tried running the PHP alone and there's no problem encountered. But when I include it on my HTML, nothings happening.

**HTML CODE:**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<?php 
include("functions/function.php");
?>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Online Shop</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='../CSS/style.css' media="all"/>
    </head>
<body>  
            <!--Main Wrapper starts here!-->
    <div class="main_wrapper"> 

            <!--Header Wrapper starts here!-->
        <div class="header_wrapper" >
        <img id="logo" src="../Pictures/logo.png"/>
        <img id="banner" src="../Pictures/green-banner.jpg"/>
        </div>
            <!--Header ends here!-->

            <!--Menu Bar starts here!-->
        <div class="menubar">
        <ul id="menu">
            <li><a href="#"> Home </a></li> 
            <li><a href="#"> All Products </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> My Account </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Sign Up </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Shopping Cart </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Contact Us  </a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="form">
            <form method="get" action="results.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="text" name="user_query"  placeholder="Search Product"/>
                <input type="submit" name="search" value="search"/>
            </form> 
        </div>
        </div><!--Menubar ends here!-->

            <!--Content Wrapper here!-->
        <div class="content_wrapper">
            <div id="sidebar"> 
                <div id="sidebar_title"> Categories</div>
                <ul id="cats">
                    <?php getCats(); ?>             
                </ul>   
            </div>
            <div id="content_area">THis is asa content</div>
        </div><!--Content Wrapper ends here!-->
        <div id="footer">  </div>
    </div><!--Wrapper-->
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP CODE:**

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","ecommerce");
//Getting Categories
function getCats(){

global $con;
$get_cats = "Select * from categories";

$run_cat = mysqli_query($con, $get_cats);

while ($row_cats=mysqli_fetch_array($run_cat)){

    $cat_id = $row_cats['cat_id'];
    $cat_title = $row_cats['cat_title'];
echo"<li><a href='#'>$cat_title</a></li>";
}
} //getCats() ENDS HERE
?>
```

**additional information:**

My HTML Path: C:/xampp/htdocs/ProjectWebDev/HTML/index.html

My PHP Path:  C:/xampp/htdocs/ProjectWebDev/functions/function.php

Comment: include("../functions/function.php");

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *"But when I include it on my HTML, nothings happening."*

You need to instruct Apache to treat `.html` files as PHP.

If you haven't, then do. `.html` files do not parse PHP directives by default.

Consult: [Using .htaccess to make all .html pages to run as .php files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687208/using-htaccess-to-make-all-html-pages-to-run-as-php-files)

and create a file called `.htaccess` and placed inside the root of your server with the following content:

`AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html`

If and when you do decide to use the .htaccess method, remember to restart your server/services/Apache/PHP. Those changes won't take effect until you do.

Plus, make sure that you do have a webserver/PHP installed and is properly configured.

If you're trying to access your files in a web browser such as:

`c://file.html` or `c://file.php`, then that won't work.

It must be used like this, e.g.:

- `http://localhost|example.com/file.html`
- `http://localhost|example.com/file.php`

Also make sure the path to your include is correct.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

Comment: "Create a .htaccess file at the root of your website and add this line:

down vote
accepted
Create a .htaccess file at the root of your website and add this line:

[Apache2 @ Ubuntu/Debian: use this directive]

AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
If your are running PHP as CGI (probably not the case), you should write instead:

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html .htm "

Sir, I quite don't get this. Does creating a .htaccess file is the same as creating html and php?  And also, What does he meant when he say : "Create a .htaccess file at the root of your website and add this line"

Comment: @user4932301 It's included in the link I added in my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687208/using-htaccess-to-make-all-html-pages-to-run-as-php-files

Comment: you create a text-based file `.htaccess` (with the dot like that) and place it in the root of your server. If you don't want to go through that trouble, then just rename your `.html` file extension to `.php`. Like I mentioned in my answer, a web browser won't parse PHP directives by default, a server does that.

Comment: @user4932301 If and when you do decide to use the `.htaccess` method, remember to restart your server/services/Apache/PHP. Those changes won't take effect until you do.

Comment: One last question, where is the "root" of a server? It may sounds stupid sorry :P. Still learning :)

Comment: @user4932301 that will depend on what your public folder is named as. Some are called htdocs, some are called public, or public_html. Yours seems to be called `htdocs`.

Comment: It's working now! Thanks Fred -ii- ! You're a big help in stackoverflow :D

Comment: @user4932301 You're most welcome (and thanks), *cheers* glad I was of help. Happy coding/happy holidays/New Year ;-)

Comment: Dears I have found this question as the closer to my question on serverfault, if you kindly can reply https://serverfault.com/questions/1065400/apache-2-4-php-7-4-include-and-require-dont-include-php-files-but-others-files

Answer (score 3):

Try this, And also change your HTML file format to **.php**. I hope it will work.

```
<?php 
include("../functions/function.php");
?>
```

Comment: Thats the same as I just wrote 10 Minutes ago

Comment: there was internet problem, sorry from my side but i did not copied you.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the path is wrong, you should use `include("../functions/function.php");`.

Also you need to rename the `.html` file to `.php` (if not diffrently configured in your server)

Comment: How do I configure it in my server?

Comment: you don't need to, but if you want to find a solution for your exact server, I can't help for that