# Setting $_SESSION variable but something doesn't work

Tags: php, html, session, variables

I am sure this is something really simple but I can't figure out what's wrong.

I have set up my html, php, and js file to work together but am having trouble with setting my own session variable and checking it across files.

I have made sure that both the HTML and PHP files contain the include for my session.php file (the file just handles session_start if not already set).

To sum it up, my HTML file has a function (userSelection aka fxn1).  This function passes a value to another function (showGameInfo aka fxn2), and my .js file handles fxn2.  Then, fxn2 sends it to the php file which spits out the information to display.  Everything works fine until I try to define my own variable. I did this inside fxn1 in the html file.  Then, I tried to echo the $_SESSION['test'] value in the php file.  This is the line I added to fxn1:

```
<?php $_SESSION['test'] = 1 ?>;
```

Am I missing something really simple here? My php file shows the SESSION is set.  Please let me know what might be wrong.

FXN1 is in my HTML file like this:

```
<script>
function userSelection(val) {
    <?php $_SESSION['test'] = 1; ?>
    showGameInfo(val);
}
</script>
```

If I take out the SESSION['test'] line in the html, the php file simply says the variable test is undefined, and displays the rest as it should.

So that tells me it's wrong in the HTML somehow..but why?

Edit1: I have included session.php in my html and php file.  session.php contains this:

```
<?php 
if (!isset($_SESSION))
    session_start();
?>
```

Is that incorrect? It's at the top of the html. And this is how it is included in the php file as well, and my php file shows isset($_SESSION) to be true, so I assume it's correct.

Comment: *"Am I missing something really simple here?"* probably `session_start();`

Comment: error reporting; is always your friend

Comment: Where are you trying to _use_ the session? You've only shown us where you set it.

Comment: *"FXN1 is in my HTML file like this:"* - define that. As in `.html` file?

Comment: @Fred-ii-, yes it is in my main .html file, defined as so.

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson, I am simply having my .php file echo it:

echo $_SESSION['test'];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *""FXN1 is in my HTML file like this:" - define that. As in .html file? – Fred -ii-"*
>
> *"@Fred-ii-, yes it is in my main .html file, defined as so. – Gredenko"*

First you need to start the session and for the `.html` file, change that to `.php` or instruct your system to treat those as php.

PHP does not parse directives with `.html` as a default.

You should also check to see if the session array is set with `isset()`.

Comment: Okay, I think that's the problem.  I read just now that <?php .. ?> doesn't work in html normally and that must be why it breaks. I changed it to a .php file and it worked.  But should I always use the .php extension then if I am going to include any php code? Or is there a more 'correct' solution? Thanks Fred.

Comment: @Gredenko You're welcome. If you want to keep using `.html` as an extension, you can instruct your system (if it supports it) to treat those as php. Here's something you can have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687208/using-htaccess-to-make-all-html-pages-to-run-as-php-files

Answer (score 1):

Start your session first using

```
session_start();
```

Then only you can work with sessions.

```
<script>
function userSelection(val) {
    <?php 
     session_start();//starts your session
      $_SESSION['test'] = 1;//sets session variable ?>
    showGameInfo(val);
}
</script>
```

For more see manual [PHP Sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php)

Comment: session_start() method is missing.

Comment: Please check my edit and the part about session.php, I have made sure to include it in both the php and html files.

Comment: how you include php file in html?save it as `main.php`

Answer (score 0):

`session_start();` must be on any page needing to define or recall session variables and must be before defining or calling the variables.

From the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) (emphasis added):

> session_start() creates a session or **resumes** the current one based on a session identifier passed via a GET or POST request, or passed via a cookie.

Also, if you want run PHP in an HTML file, you would need to add this to a .htaccess file in your folder

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm .html
```