# PHP code in Htm and HTML pages

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, cpanel

My index.html file

```html
<html> 
    <head>
        <title> PHP inside HTML </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>
            <?php
                  echo "PHP Output";
            ?>
        </h1>
        <h1>
            <p>
                HTML Output
            </p>
        </h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

My Expected output of the above code:

**PHP Output

HTML Output**

I have tried with below combinations but none of these helps me get the output.

`AddHandler application/x-httpd-php56 .shtml .html .htm`
`AddHandler server-parsed .shtml .shtm .htm .html`
`AddHandler x-httpd-php .html .htm`
`AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .html .htm`

2nd Set of Codes Not Working

`AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .htm`
`AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html`
`AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm`
`AddType application/x-httpd-php .html`

3rd Set of Codes Not Working.

`AddHandler x-httpd-php5 .html`
`AddHandler x-httpd-php5 .htm`
`AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .htm`
`AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html`

## While adding the Mime types using the .htaccess.

`AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm`
`AddType application/x-httpd-php .html`

It leads to download the files instead of working.

## Returns Internal Server Error

`Options +ExecCGIenter`
`AddHandler fcgid-script .html`
`FCGIWrapper /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/php5 .html`

Please help me to resolve this issue.

I have referred the page in stack-overflow but all of the codes are not working for me.
[StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687208/using-htaccess-to-make-all-html-pages-to-run-as-php-files)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using .htaccess to make all .html pages to run as .php files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687208/using-htaccess-to-make-all-html-pages-to-run-as-php-files)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your account's under `Cloudlinux` based server then use the below code, Hope it will work fine.

## Code

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php56 .htm .html .shtml

AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .php
```

Consider the `PHP` versions and modify the code accordingly.