# How to use PHP7 code in HTML file with the help of .htaccess setting

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I am using linux server and in my server I have install PHP 7.* version. I want to use PHP code in HTML file. Right now it render PHP code in in web page.  I am using the following code in my .htaccess file but it not working.

```
AddHandler x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

and

```
AddHandler php7-script .php .html .htm
```

and

```
<FilesMatch "\.html?$">
SetHandler application/x-httpd-php7
</FilesMatch>
```

But all are these not working.

Comment: Are you running Apache or Nginx? If Apache, try: `AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687208/using-htaccess-to-make-all-html-pages-to-run-as-php-files

Comment: @Magnus Running Apache. When I am using 
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm 
it downloads the file with the html code.

Comment: You can only use .htaccess files when [AllowOverride](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/core.html#allowoverride) in the parent Directory is set to true. Also, are you sure the php module is loaded in the Apache? Check enabled-modules directory.

Comment: @Gordon If it tries to download the file when the OP is setting the AddHandler in htacess, then it's safe to assume that the htaccess was loaded and used. Otherwise, it would simply be ignored without any change.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson yeah, but if there is one thing I learned at StackOverflow, then that it's safer to verify than to assume though.

Comment: Check how the PHP module in Apache is registering the `php`-extension (check the `php7.conf` in the Apache mods-folder) and use the same for htm and html? Where you find it depends on the linux dist (default for Ubuntu is: `/etc/apache2/mods-available/...`

Comment: I have check the addition module list with the phpinfo() function. There has no module loaded in this list. So I need to load it first?

Comment: The php module for Apache, not a php library. If that wasn't loaded, Apache wouldn't be able to parse PHP-files.

Comment: Why you want to write `PHP` code into `HTML` file instead of writing into `PHP` file?

Comment: I have done it by adding AddType x-mapp-php4 .html .htm and remove  SetHandler application/x-httpd-php7. @FahadKazmi I got the code from any other prerson, I have no idea why he use php in html.

Comment: What web server (incl. version) do you use ? Apache2 ?

Answer (score 1):

After you installed php7.0-cgi

```
sudo apt install php7.0-cgi

you can add to your .htaccess

AddHandler php70-cgi .php
```

tells Apache to run PHP on any file with the extension ".php"
using the Module called php70-cgi that is afaik modules/php70-cgi.so

A reason why its not working could be the webserver settings in

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/default
```

if there is  `AllowOverride`  „None“ set it to  „All“ else you can only make setting in `<Directory>` and not in `.htaccess`

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    ...
    AllowOverride All
    ...
</Directory>
```