# Require php line of code not working

Tags: php, html, require

Very new to all of this and having some issues using a line of code.

All i am trying to do is have my html file have a require statement that pulls a php file however it is not working. Please help.

```
<?php
require 'localhost/php/loginscreen.php';
?>
```

Comment: Attach error code and environments to how it does not work

Comment: you should be getting an error for this; incorrect syntax. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Please read the documentation on that http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php and try again.

Comment: Strange as there is no error. as i refresh my html file nothing happens.

Comment: *"Strange as there is no error. as i refresh my html file nothing happens"* - Now that makes this question unclear. Just how exactly are you trying to use this; as `http://localhost` or as `file:///`? and what type of file extension? You're not using an `.html` as a base file, are you?

Comment: Yep i read this earlier and tried <?php require 'php/loginscreen.php';?> as the file is in a different folder however still nothing

Comment: Damm! yes its me being dumb, i was using the old html base file instead of the php one. sorry to waste your time

Comment: @jRogers Well, I didn't think it was dumb, just something you may not have remembered/noticed. You didn't waste our time; least not mine and I've posted an answer below if you wish to mark it off as solved. It's voluntary but it does inform everyone that the question was solved. Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"All i am trying to do is have my html file have a require statement that pulls a php file however it is not working"*.

That to me suggests that you're using an `.html` file as a base file to pull in an `.php` file.

Unless you've instructed your server to treat `.html` files as PHP, you would need to rename that file to a `.php` extension.

Edit. Consult the following Q&A on Stack on how to do this:

- [Using .htaccess to make all .html pages to run as .php files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687208/using-htaccess-to-make-all-html-pages-to-run-as-php-files)

Your syntax for `require 'localhost/php/loginscreen.php';` is incorrect.

You would need to either use a full system path: (as an example, replace that with your system path).

```
require '/var/usr/public/php/loginscreen.php';
```

or a relative path:

```
require 'php/loginscreen.php';
```

and using `http://localhost` rather than a possible `file:///` url in the browser.

> [*"Strange as there is no error. as i refresh my html file nothing happens."*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45807142/require-php-line-of-code-not-working/45807220#comment78572075_45807142)

Had you viewed your HTML source, you would have most likely have seen code, rather than parsed (PHP) directives. That would have been the reason why you did not see any errors, least not php-wise.

Comment: One shouldn't downvote a perfectly good answer just because one didn't like something I did without reason.