# how to parse php file inside of html file

Tags: php, apache2.4

Could someone help me configure my `httpd.conf` server file so I can execute simple php code run as .html file?

The browser outputs nothing or is just blank.  (ex. )

php version - 7.2.8
server version - Apache/2.4.34 (Fedora)

Comment: Normally the browser can interpret html and your server can interpret PHP. So I don't undertand the question. Perhaps show an example of what you need to do. Is it how to configure Apache for PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create .htaccess file in your project directory and use below code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule index.html index.php
```

replace index with your script file name

Comment: this simple solution worked!  saved me some frustrations.    thanks for the advice, suggestions and valuable responses here!

Answer (score 0):

**you should save your html file with php Format or Using .htaccess to make all .html pages to run as .php files :**  

 First way:

> file.html most convert to file.php

you most Run your web service and then open your file with logical address
http://localhost/file.php

Secund Way:
Create a .htaccess file at the root of your website and add this line:

[Apache2 @ Ubuntu/Debian: use this directive]

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

Or, from comment below:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .html .htm
```

If your are running PHP as CGI (probably not the case), you should write instead:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

[Using .htaccess to make all .html pages to run as .php files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687208/using-htaccess-to-make-all-html-pages-to-run-as-php-files)