# include 'x.php' not working on html pages

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

on my site the topbar, menu and footer as php include instruction in html, is not working for the *.html files
only the index.html

In the chrome inspector i see that de php include is shown as command!
when is rename the agenda.html -> agenda.php the php_menu, php_topbar and php_footer are working again

in the past i have to put a "addhandler" in the ".htaccess"

How can i make al html to run as a php

---

### index.html

```
<!--Top bar start-->
<?php
    include 'php_topbar.php';
?>
```

---

### php_footer.php

https://www.sportenmoedig.be/php_footer.php

---

php version:
https://sportenmoedig.be/version.php

Current PHP version: 7.3.23

---

### .htaccess

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php .htm .shtml .html

---

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using .htaccess to make all .html pages to run as .php files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687208/using-htaccess-to-make-all-html-pages-to-run-as-php-files)

Answer (score -1):

You can't use `<?php ?>` tags in `html` page, `<?php ?>` working only in php file. You can change `index.html` to `index.php`

Answer (score -1):

The opening of PHP script is `<?php` and the closing will be `?>`

Outside of these tags, you will be able to insert your html. This means that any page that you want to use PHP in you should name a .php file.

This source will help you understand how PHP and HTML can be used together:

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_syntax.asp